# HTML: How to set element width to the smallest of either (a) the screen width or (b) some size in pixels?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make an element 400 px wide, if that fits the screen, and otherwise just give it the full width of the screen.

So I don't want the element to overflow beyond the screen.

How do I do this actually?

I've tried setting max-width to 400px, that works partly but it doesn't (of course) set the initial size. If I also put width=100% on it I notice that as I make the window smaller at a certain point the item starts (slightly) overflowing off the screen - it doesn't do that with only max-width set.

Comment: are you wanting to set a max-width of an element to 400px and otherwise set it to 100% width? Can you show us your codes and samples of desire results? Your question is not very clear

Answer (score 2):

To have a set width and a max width you can do the following:

```
element {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
{
```

This will set the default width of your element to 100% of the elements parent, but will cap the width at 400px. One thing to take note of is that this will make the elements width 100% of the PARENT to your element. Not of the window.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, the flex items are set to evenly occupy the entirety of its parent's width. But, they will only go as far as 400px in a screen that fits 400px. Otherwise, they're as big as their parent will allow them.

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#flex-item-1 {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background-color: red;
  height: inherit;
  max-width: 400px;
}

#flex-item-2 {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background-color: orange;
  height: inherit;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div id="flex-item-1"></div>
  <div id="flex-item-2"></div>
</div>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/EOXyqR)

On the side note, check out this [guide for flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) :)